# I tried a floating div over an image but doesn't work

Tags: html, css

[My Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/op8tw.png)

I want to make text-box/a box over an image with div, i already tried this but why it can't.

My code goes here:

HTML/CSS :

```css
.main{
 position: relative;
 margin: 8;
}
.main img{
 position: relative;
 height: 510px;
 width: 100%;
}
.main-content{
 position: absolute;
 background: white;
 height: 40px;
 width: 40px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>PokeMart</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
 <div class="header">
  <img src="valor.png">
  <h3>PokeMart</h3>
  <h4><a href="#">Login</a></h4>
  <h4><a href="#">Register</a></h4>
 </div>
 <div class="main">
  <img src="bg.jpg" />
  <div class="main-content">Text</div>
 </div>
 <div class="footer">
  <h5>Pokemart established 2017, powered by Pokemon Company</h5>
  <h5>Copyright © 2017 LL. All Right Reserved.</h5>
  <div class="contact">
   <img src="facebook.png" width="25" height="25">
   <img src="google.png" width="25" height="25">
   <img src="twitter.png" width="25" height="25">
   <img src="github.png" width="25" height="25">
   <img src="instagram.png" width="25" height="25">
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>`
```

CSS code just the floating div, I have tried Display: Inline-block still don't work.

Comment: try with float:left/right

Comment: Apply position:absolute; and adjust it with top and right.. for ex - position:absolute;top:100px;right:100px;

Comment: Does the image serve a function on the page? If not, you should turn it into a css background image.

Comment: @Reinaldi If any of the solution worked for you, it'd be appreciated if you mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using absolute positioning but not directing where the content should be placed. Try using **top,left,right,bottom** to *adjust the content position*.

```
top:20%;
right:100px;
```

```css
.main {
  position: relative;
  margin: 8;
}

.main img {
  position: relative;
  height: 510px;
  width: 100%;
}

.main-content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20%;
  right: 100px;
  background: white;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>PokeMart</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="header">
    <img src="valor.png">
    <h3>PokeMart</h3>
    <h4><a href="#">Login</a></h4>
    <h4><a href="#">Register</a></h4>
  </div>
  <div class="main">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/9000x500" />
    <div class="main-content">Text</div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer">
    <h5>Pokemart established 2017, powered by Pokemon Company</h5>
    <h5>Copyright © 2017 LL. All Right Reserved.</h5>
    <div class="contact">
      <img src="facebook.png" width="25" height="25">
      <img src="google.png" width="25" height="25">
      <img src="twitter.png" width="25" height="25">
      <img src="github.png" width="25" height="25">
      <img src="instagram.png" width="25" height="25">
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>`
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.wrap {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  position: relative;
  max-width: 450px;
}
.wrap img {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.wrap .overlay {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  display: flex;
}
.wrap .overlay .box {
  margin: auto;
  background-color: #FFF;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <img src="http://www.telegraph.co.uk/content/dam/gaming/2017/10/10/Pokemon-Halloween_trans_NvBQzQNjv4BqZPnXlBHEdt8AtjizIYNgmRSlK0RKxqt6w8JJghUtSuI.jpg?imwidth=450">
  <div class="overlay">
    <div class="box">box</div>
  </div>
</div>
```